# How many times does $k$ occur in the composition of $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-partitions

How many times does the number $k$ occur in the composition of $n$?

[Composition of Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))

In short, the difference between the partition of an integer and composition is the order of numbers. In partition, the order doesn't matter whereas, in composition, it does. That's why Partitions are sometimes called as ordered Compositions.

Example: $k$ = $1$ & $n$ = $5$

The composition of 5 are:

$5$

$4 + 1$

$3 + 2$

$3 + 1 + 1$

$2 + 3$

$2 + 2 + 1$

$2 + 1 + 2$

$2 + 1 + 1 + 1$

$1 + 4$

$1 + 3 + 1$

$1 + 2 + 2$

$1 + 2 + 1 + 1$

$1 + 1 + 3$

$1 + 1 + 2 + 1$

$1 + 1 + 1 + 2$

$1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$

In all $1$ occurs $28$ times in the composition of $5$

Similarly is there any relation between $k$ and $n$ for all $n \geq 0$ & $k \leq n$

Comment: You probably mean decomposition ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics) @YvesDaoust  I meant this.

Comment: And perhaps a more common terms is "partition".

Comment: @JohnHughes A partition is an unordered sum. Compositions are sometimes called 'ordered partitions'.  "Composition" is fairly standard though.

Comment: @JohnHughes  No, In partition the order doesn't matter whereas is composition of a number, the order does matter

Comment: Thanks...I should have looked at the examples more carefully.

Comment: in order to have less confused readers, you could edit the question with the link and the quick definition. I don't think John is alone in never having met these before.

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C12%2C28&language=english&go=Search ... 1,2,5,12,28,64,..

Comment: Worth noting from @DonaldSplutterwit link; according to OEIS, the number of $1$s in the compositions of $n+1$ equals the number of $2$s in the compositions of $n+2$ equals the number of $3$s in the composition of $n+3$... so understanding $k=1$ and the relationship mention in the link should suffice. Now just to work out the proofs...

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $k$ (such that $0<k<n$) occurs at "*position $p$*" in a composition of $n$: $$\ldots+k+\ldots$$
by which I mean that everything to its left is a composition of $p$, and everything to its right is a composition of $n-p-k$.

If $p>0$ and $n-p-k>0$, there are $2^{p-1}$ compositions of $p$ and $2^{n-p-k-1}$ compositions of $n-p-k$, thus there are $2^{p-1}\cdot2^{n-p-k-1}=2^{n-k-2}$ possibilities for the rest of the composition of $n$. If $p=0$ or $n-p-k=0$, there are $2^{n-k-1}$ possibilities for the rest of the composition of $n$.

Summing over $p$, you will find that for $k<n$ the answer is: $$2\cdot2^{n-k-1}+\sum_{p=1}^{n-k-1}2^{n-k-2}=(n-k+3)\cdot2^{n-k-2}$$

Comment: smart approach, and the formula checks correctly (+1)! I just put position in Italic to underline that it is not to be confused with the position in the sequence.

Comment: What is the meaning of position here?

Answer (score 2):

First, for $k=1$. Let $a(n)$ be the number of times $1$ appears in the compositions of $n+1$ (as per the OEIS indexing). Then a composition of $n+1$ either ends in $1,2,3,\dots$. The compositions ending in $1$ contribute $a(n-1)+2^{n-1}$ (since there are $2^{n-1}$ total compositions of $n$). The compositions ending in $j$, $j\geq 2$, contribute $a(n-j)$; thus we get the recurrence 
$$
a(n)=2^{n-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a(j),
$$
with $a(0)=1$. A straightforward induction proof (just manipulate a few sums) shows $a(n)=(n+3)2^{n-2}$ for $n\geq1$.

For a general $k$, the recursion is essentially the same, but with different initial conditions. Let $a_k(n)$ be the number of times $k$ appears in the compositions of $n+1$. Then clearly $a_j=0$ for $j<k-1$ and $a_{k-1}=1$. Now as before  condition a composition based on its last letter. We get 
$$
a_k(n)=2^{n-k-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_k(j)=2^{n-k-1}+\sum_{j=k-1}^{n-1}a_k(j)
$$
I will leave the details but from inspection you can see from a change of variables and induction that $$a_k(n)=a_1(n-k+1)=(n-k+4)2^{n-k-1}$$

Comment: Did you leave out the extrapolation part on purpose?

Comment: Yes, my thought was that it was too long for a comment but that someone else might be able to use it for a full answer. I think I have the completed version though and am working through the details

Answer (score 0):

It's recursively defined.  Think about it, if k happens in the composition of n then it was tagged on to a composition of n-k. This implies, that there are at least as many k's in compositions of n, as there are compositions of n-k). so you can sum the number of such compositions of earlier positive numbers in the arithmetic progression $kx+(n \bmod k)$. So, for you k=1, n=5 example we have:

compositions of 1:

$$\color{red}1$$

for 2 we have :
$$\color{red}
1,\color {green}1\\
\color{green}2
$$
for 3 we have:
$$\color{green}{1,1},\color{blue}1\\
\color{green}2,\color{blue}1\\
\color{blue}3$$

for 4 we have:
$$\color{blue}{1,1,1},\color{purple}1\\
\color{blue}{2,1},\color{purple}1\\
\color{blue}{3},\color{purple}1\\\color{purple}{2,2}\\\color{purple}4$$

and for 5 we have:

$$\color{purple}{1,1,1,1},\color{lime}1\\
\color{purple}{2,1,1},\color{lime}1\\
\color{purple}{3,1},\color{lime}1\\\color{purple}{2,2},\color{lime}1\\\color{purple}4,\color{lime}1\\\color{lime}5$$

So, let $f(n,k)$ be the the number of such compositions for the value of n, and let g(v) be the number of compositions of v total:

$$f(n,k)=\sum_{i\gt0,i\equiv n\bmod k}^n g(v) +f(n\bmod k,k)$$

Answer (score 0):

The generating function here is

$$G(z, u) = \sum_{q\ge 1} \left(uz^k - z^k + \frac{z}{1-z}\right)^q.$$

We then have that

$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1}
\\ = \left. \sum_{q\ge 1}
q \left(uz^k - z^k + \frac{z}{1-z}\right)^{q-1} z^k\right|_{u=1}
= z^k \sum_{q\ge 1} q \left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^{q-1}
\\ = z^k \frac{1}{(1-z/(1-z))^2}
= z^k \frac{1-2z+z^2}{(1-2z)^2}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find for $n\ge k+2$

$$[z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-2z)^2}
- 2[z^{n-k-1}] \frac{1}{(1-2z)^2}
+ [z^{n-k-2}] \frac{1}{(1-2z)^2}
\\ = 2^{n-k} (n-k+1) - 2^{n-k} (n-k) + 2^{n-k-2} (n-k-1)
\\ = 2^{n-k} + 2^{n-k-2} (n-k-1)
= 2^{n-k-2} (n-k+3).$$

We get for $n=k+1$

$$2^{n-k} (n-k+1) - 2^{n-k} (n-k) = 2$$

which corresponds to $(1,k)$ and $(k,1)$
and for $n=k$

$$2^{n-k} (n-k+1) = 1.$$

These only depend on $n-k$ as pointed out in the comments.